# How && works in JavaScript if isn't in a control statement?

Tags: javascript, operators

Recently I was working with some JavaScript code and I found this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.localStorage&&window.localStorage.clear();
</script>
```

I did research around the web but didn't find anything about how actually that '&&' operator works if isn't in a control statement.

Does anyone know how it works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's the same as:

```
if(window.localStorage){
    window.localStorage.clear();
}
```

The `&&` short-circuits as soon as it sees a `false` (or "falsy") value.

So, if `window.localStorage` is `false` (or "falsy"), it stops.  If it's true, it continues and runs `window.localStorage.clear()`.  The return value is ignored.

Comment: Heeey! Thanks a lot, this is a really good trick!! There's another similar tricks?

Comment: @FelipeLeñero: There's `?:`.  `var c = x ? a : b` is the same as `var c; if(x){c=a}else{c=b}`.  There's also `||`.  `var d = a || b || c`.  `d` will be set to the first not "falsy" value of `a`, `b`, and `c`.

Answer (score 1):

```
if this code evaluates to a truthy value&&run this code
```

Answer (score 0):

Whether part of a control statement or not, an expression is an expression. In this case the expression involves boolean operations. So the expression will evaluate the second part if first one is `true`.

In this case it will execute the clear() method on `window.localStorage` only if `window.localStorage` is not `null`.